# How to convert Latitud and Longitud to Google GeoPoint?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geo

How to convert Latitud and Longitud to Google GeoPoint?

My Latitud is:      47.523009954564536
My Long is :        19.01667991207027

And when i try to convert to GeoPoints with:

```
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1e6),
                              (int)(longitude * 1e6));
```

the results are:
4.7523009E7
1.901671E7

Which is clearly wrong cause im not typing from the Gulf of Guinea (Africa)
I need values tarts with the 47 and 19 integers not 4. and 1. decimals.

I saw this kind of convertation in many pages but somehow its not good for me.
Help please !

Answer (score 1):

There may be a casting error, try and use this method:

> ```
> public static GeoPoint calculateGeoPoint(double latitude, double longitude) {
>     Double latE6 = latitude * 1E6;
>     Double lngE6 = longitude * 1E6;
>     return  new GeoPoint(latE6.intValue(), lngE6.intValue());
> }
> ```

taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773058/android-geopoint-error)

thanks.

Comment: Damn.. same results. maybe something wrong with my latidue and longtidue

Comment: try and remove some of the trailing digits, keep both numbers at 6 decimal places.

Comment: Yes Hungary. Im just lost a little in numbers and conversions.

Comment: Have you tried to make your lat and long have less digits after the decimal point?

Comment: Well not yet. Im just a little confused of all this.

Answer (score 0):

```
GeoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(22.30 * 1E6),(int)(70.80 * 1E6));
```

try this it works...